# c# Alpha Telephone Number Translator

Tags: c#, foreach, enums, switch-statement

I have a homework assignment where the program will accept any phone number in the format similar to 555-GET-FOOD.  The task is to map the alphabetic letters to numbers and translate the number to its numeric equivalent.
For example:  A, B, C = 2; D, E, F = 3; etc...

We have not covered Classes or creating maps at this point so these would not be viable solutions.  This chapter does cover the enum so I am working to solve using an Enumerated type. I have a method set up to validate the data (ensure the correct # of characters and the hyphens are in the correct place) and this does work correctly.  I have another method set up to remove the hyphens and also uses the ToUpper() method and this also works correctly, so the foreach loop I have set up us using the number after these two methods have already finished.

I have also set up a method to run after the conversion takes place to add the hyphens back in and this also works.

I have tried several ways to get is to work and have left them in commented out on the chance they might be what I need to use, for my attempt with the switch statement I only set up with the letter A for now, and plan to finish the remaining letters if I am able to get this to work.  I think the one my issues is the foreach loop is using a char type and the switch is using an int.  Seems to be the same issue when trying the code inside the foreach loop but I am not sure how to fix so any suggestions are appreciated.

```
public enum AlphaNumber
{ 
    A=2, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=3, F=3, G=4, H=4, I=4, J=5, K=5, L=5, 
    M=6, N=6, O=6, P=7, Q=7, R=7, S=8, T=8, U=8, V=9, W=9, X=9, Y=9, Z=9
}
 private void UpdatePhone(AlphaNumber phone)
    {
        switch (phone)
        {
            case AlphaNumber.A:
           //return AlphaNumber.(int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlphaNumber));
           //return (Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlphaNumber)));
           //   (int)ValueType;
                Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlphaNumber));
                break;                   
        }
private void translateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numberLabel.Text = "";//Clear the numberLabel
        //Get a trimmed copy of the user's input.  
        string input = numberTextBox.Text.Trim();

        if (IsValidFormat(input))
        {
            Unformat(ref input);

            foreach (char ch in input)
            {
                if (char.IsLetter(ch))//                    {
                    ch = (char)Enums.AlphaNumber.Active;
                    //ch = (char)Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlphaNumber));
                    //ch = Enum.TryParse(AlphaNumber);
                   // ch = AlphaNumber.(int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(AlphaNumber));
                    //UpdatePhone(ch);
                   MessageBox.Show("Character is char");                    }
            }

            TelephoneFormat(ref input);    
            numberLabel.Text = input;
```

I am open to any suggestions and appreciate any help provided. Where I need help is inside the foreach loop, I am looking at each value and if it is a letter I want to get the value from the enum values and replace the char with the number value.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: SO, solving homework assignments since 2008

Comment: Sorry, I updated the post so hopefully it is now easier to understand.  I am looking for help with my code inside the foreach loop.  I have it set up to look at each char and if the char is a letter, I want it to return the value of the Enum.  I have tried both the switch statement and AlphaNumber.Active and have not been able to get either to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `enum` and the `switch`, and instead do a lookup against a map. I have created a .NET Fiddle that demonstrates this working as desired [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o5oDWs).

But if using a `Dictionary<char, char>` is for some odd reason out of question, then I suppose you could use [this version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cuwFBY) -- in which I use the `enum`. It is just a lot more work and the more moving parts you have the harder it is to maintain.

In `C#` the type `enum` inherits from `int` by default, but you can specify various other numeric types -- like `byte` or `long`, etc... One of the key takeaways is the concept of boxing/unboxing and casting/converting from one type to another. If you have an `enum` defined as `enum Foo { Bar = 63 }` and [you try](https://dotnetfiddle.net/phlYTS) to `cast` it to a `char` what would you expect to get?

This actually would result in the char `?` -- take a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and the find the `DEC` for 63 and look at what it maps to for the `Char` column.

The issue is fixed with this crazy complicated mess:

```
    public enum AlphaNumber
    { 
        A=2, B=2, C=2, D=3, E=3, F=3, G=4, H=4, I=4, J=5, K=5, L=5, 
        M=6, N=6, O=6, P=7, Q=7, R=7, S=8, T=8, U=8, V=9, W=9, X=9, Y=9, Z=9
    }

    public static class PhoneNumber
    {
        public static char ParseInput(char input)
        {
            if (input == '-' || char.IsDigit(input))
            {
                return input;
            }

            if (char.IsLetter(input))
            {
                var num = (AlphaNumber)(Enum.Parse(typeof(AlphaNumber), (char.IsLower(input) ? char.ToUpperInvariant(input) : input).ToString()));
                return ((int)num).ToString()[0];
            }

            return '\0';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I looked at your example and watched a video  and did some reading to help understand but will have to study them a bit more to use as I am not following all the code at this point.  I follow most but a few items I wasn't sure of and really want to be sure I understand before using.  I really would like to stick with the concepts we are covering but if I am not able to resolve I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

While "map" (implemented as `Dictionary` in C#/.Net) is probably best choice for this problem, basic math is enough for such simple transformation:

```
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join("",  // combine characters back to string
       "555-GET-FOOD" //value
          .ToUpperInvariant() // carefully converting to avoid Turkish I problems
          .Select(c=> (c>='A' && c<='Z') ? // only tweak A-Z range
             Math.Min((c-'A')/3+2,9).ToString()[0] : c)))
```

Comment: Sorry as I did not explain my need very well but have since updated so hopefully it is not more clear.  I am looking to update the phone number's char values that are letter's with a numbers using an enum.  I am trying to accomplish using either a switch or the .Active code but keep getting error messages.  I have some of the code I have tried without success commented out but it is there on the change it might be able to be used with minor tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did attempt to use `TryParse`:

`//ch = Enum.TryParse(AlphaNumber);`

That is the method that you probably want to use.  But there are a number of problems with it in that form, which probably gave you errors as you mentioned.

The parameters this method expects are a `string` (which matches the enumerated constant, or name from the `enum`) and an `out` parameter of the type of the `enum` you want to parse.  The method return a `bool`.

If the `TryParse` is successful then the method returns TRUE with the corresponding value from the `enum` set in the `out` parameter.

This code should allow you to get the result you want as an `int` using your variable `ch` as a `string` for the input to parse:

```
AlphaNumber parsedCh;
int? chValue = null;

if (Enum.TryParse(ch.ToString().ToUpper(), out parsedCh)) 
{
    chValue = (int)parsedCh;
    Console.WriteLine(chValue); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have to work in the morning so I will try this out after work.

Comment: While I don't need to finish the project now, I wanted to let you know I was able to use a variation of this and I just needed to get it assigned back to the ch variable in the actual phone #.  It looks like you modified a little, but I had to remove the '=null' as I was getting an error in order to get it to work.  This is so simple but it works awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AlphaPhoneToNumber("555-GET-FOOD"));
    }

    public static string AlphaPhoneToNumber(string val){
        //strings are immutable so let's get the array version of the value
        var phoneNumberArr = val.ToCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++){
            phoneNumberArr[i] = AlphaPhoneCharToNumber(phoneNumberArr[i]);
        }
        return new string(phoneNumberArr);
    }

    public static char AlphaPhoneCharToNumber(char val){
        switch(val){
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                return '2';
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                return '3';
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
                return '4';
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                return '5';
            case 'M':
            case 'N':
            case 'O':
                return '6';
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
                return '7';
            case 'S':
            case 'T':
            case 'U':
                return '8';
            case 'V':
            case 'W':
            case 'X':
            case 'Y':
            case 'Z':
                return '9';
            default: return val;

        }
    }
}
```

and here's how to do it without switch:

```
public static char AlphaPhoneCharToNumber2(char val){
    // All three arrays are of exact same length
    var ualphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    var lalphas = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
    var numval =  "22233344455566677788899999".ToCharArray();
    // thus I will loop up to the max length of one of the arrays
    // remember they are all the same length
    for(int i = 0; i < ualphas.Length; i++){
        //I will check if the value is in one of the alphabet
        //arrays at the current index
        //if there is a match I will assign it the number value
        //at the same index
        // MATCH UPPER?         MATCH LOWER?              RETURN NUMBER
        if(ualphas[i] == val || lalphas[i] == val) return numval[i];
    }
    // ELSE RETURN THE ORIGINAL VALUE
    return val;
}
```

Comment: I tried the option without the switch and it is still returning the Letter instead of the number.  I put the statement calling the method inside the foreach loop.   AlphaPhoneCharToNumber2(ch);  Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @cccstudent I just replaced the char operation 'AlphaPhoneCharToNumber' with the second one 'AlphaPhoneCharToNumber2' and I get numbers?

Comment: DOES NOT WORK WITH LOWERCASE CHARS

Comment: Thanks for your answers Chris, I had previous to this part of the assignment used the ToUpper, so I used just the two arrays with the upper letters and numbers, I wasn't able to get it to work and was planning to keep working with your suggestion as the code made sense to me and I felt it should work but now I do not need to finish but still wanted to thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for simple logic to process phone numbers as described.
Note that while a novel approach, using an Enum to map letters to integer values somewhat complicates the process more than it needed to be.

Even though other methods exist for specifically mapping alpha-numeric phone numbers (think Regex) if you do ever need to iterate or process using Enum Names and Values then I hope you find these algorithms useful.

> A dictionary would have been far simpler as a mapping construct to process from.
>
> Regex where the LetterNumber mapping is defined in the expression would have been superior again.

```
/// <summary>
/// Iterates through the characters in a phone number converting letters to digits.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Uses StringBuilder to build the output iteratively, this method does not attempt to validate the number passed in</remarks>
/// <see cref="LetterNumber"/>
/// <param name="str">Phone number to parse</param>
/// <returns>Phone number output where letters have been parsed into their digit values</returns>
private string ParsePhoneNumber_StringBuilder(string str)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char ch in str.ToCharArray())
    {
        // Convert each letter to it's numeric value as defined in the LetterNumber enum
        // Dashes are not letters so they will get passed through
        if (char.IsLetter(ch))
        {
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(LetterNumber), ch.ToString()))
            {
                LetterNumber letterNumber = (LetterNumber)Enum.Parse(typeof(LetterNumber), ch.ToString(), true);
                output.Append((int)letterNumber);
            }
        }
        else
            output.Append(ch);
    }
    return output.ToString();
}

/// <summary>
/// Uses Linq to parse the characters in a phone number converting letters to digits.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This method does not attempt to validate the number passed in</remarks>
/// <see cref="LetterNumber"/>
/// <param name="str">Phone number to parse</param>
/// <returns>Phone number output where letters have been parsed into their digit values</returns>
private string ParsePhoneNumber_Linq(string str)
{
    return String.Join("", str.Select(c => char.IsLetter(c) ? ((int)((LetterNumber)Enum.Parse(typeof(LetterNumber), c.ToString(), true))).ToString() : c.ToString()));
}

/// <summary>
/// Iterates through the LetterNumber values and replaces values found in the passed in phone number.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Iterates through Enum Names and applied String.Replace</remarks>
/// <see cref="LetterNumber"/>
/// <param name="str">Phone number to parse</param>
/// <returns>Phone number output where letters have been parsed into their digit values</returns>
private string ParsePhoneNumber_Replacement(string str)
{
    str = str.ToUpper(); // we will compare all letters in upper case
    foreach (string letter in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LetterNumber)))
        str = str.Replace(letter.ToUpper(), ((int)((LetterNumber)Enum.Parse(typeof(LetterNumber), letter))).ToString());
    return str;
}
```