# c# replace a char at a certain position in an input string

Tags: c#, replace, char

Given an telephone number input such as "555-GET-FOOD", I'm trying to replace the letters with their corresponding numbers (i.e. A, B, and C = 1). So far I have this:

```
public enum LetterNumber
{
    A = 2, B = 2, C = 2, D = 3, E = 3, F = 3, G = 4, H = 4, I = 4,
    J = 5, K = 5, L = 5, M = 6, N = 6, O = 6, P = 7, Q = 7, R = 7,
    S = 7, T = 8, U = 8, V = 8, W = 9, Y = 9, Z = 9
}

private bool IsValidNumber(string str)
{
    const int VALID_LENGTH = 10;
    bool valid = true;

    if (str.Length == VALID_LENGTH)
    {
        foreach (char ch in str)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(ch))
            {
                valid = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what command to use to replace each character at its given position with the number, or how to use that command. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: use Arrays - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Suspiciously similar questions nearly one year ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931403/c-sharp-alpha-telephone-number-translator Does everybody in that class use SO to solve their assignments?

Comment: I hope that in the online classes you picked up some background logic around how to process strings and how to interact with enums. My answer on this duplicate might help you with options around processing enums: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43039078/1690217